# Xcode: Creating a profile requires having a device registered in the Member Center

Tags: ios, xcode

[fix issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utyK4.png)

I get this problem when I try to "fix issue" in Xcode. I'm not using a developer's account but am following this guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hjcUbyTvslA to install Pokemon GO Anywhere on my iPhone without jailbreak. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question and is asking about how to cheat at a game.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend this at all. Apps that aren't downloaded through trusted means (ex. App Store) can contain viruses and many other bad stuff. But you need a developers account to install Xcode apps on your phone.